# Call webservice from gps device

Tags: web-services, soap, gps

I have a web service which I want to call from GPS device. I have hosted this web service on hosted server and this web service has a method called upload. This method accept a string parameter.

Currently I am calling this web service from a mobile phone with this url http://www.abc.com/Default.asmx/Upload?str=1,73.0667,33.6

Now I want to call this web method from GPS device, the problem is that GPS device accept only IP address and port no. It does not accept URL and web method.

Comment: Removed tag for C# as this has to do with executing a SOAP request from your GPS device and not your Web Service.  Suggest you specifically identify your GPS device in question - it may very well be that your device has no support for SOAP calls.

Comment: I see no question here.  Did you have a question?

Answer (score 0):

Create a proxy service which is callable by the GPS device ("IP address and port no."), which in turn makes the desired webservice call, does whatever formatting to the data is needed, and returns it to the GPS device in whatever format you want it for the GPS device.

Comment: Chris, thanks for your reply, can you please guide me on how to build proxy service and how to deploy it on hosted web servers. Any working example is appreciated